# PHP passing a class as a reference?

Tags: php, python

in Python, you could do something like this:

```
class SomeClass(object): pass
s = SomeClass
someClassInstance = s()
```

How could you accomplish the same effect in PHP? From what I understand, you cannot do this? Is this true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create instances of dynamic class names; simply pass the name of the class as a string:

```
class SomeClass {}
$s = 'SomeClass';
$someClassInstance = new $s();
```

Comment: If you're that paranoid, get a computer that runs PHP 5.2 and run it yourself. (You did it in the last 3 hours since posting that comment, I'm sure?)

Comment: School blocks FTP. Can't go into my php 5.2 test server ATM, which is why I asked :P

Comment: Well, that bites. So did mine :/

Comment: Sometimes school blocks the most senseless thing. This website was once blocked. I don't have anywhere saying that this doesn't work under PHP 5.2.

Comment: @ultimatebuster, the comment http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php#98641 suggests that it works on 5.2.

Answer (score 1):

Using reflection:

```
class SomeClass {}
$s = new ReflectionClass('SomeClass');
$someClassInstance = $s->newInstance();
```

The nice thing about using reflection is that it throws a catchable exception in the event the class does not exist.