# php: new object from "ClassName" and array of args

Tags: php, classname

I have string containing classname and an array of args.
$classname($args) works, but in this case I have only 1 argument in constructor
Anyone know, how to do this with args expanded?

Comment: Remember to accept an answer, if it helps you with your problem. This refers to your other questions too.

Answer (score 7):

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass($classname);
$object = $reflection->newInstanceArgs($args);
```

http://php.net/reflection

Comment: Before reflection, I had this exact same problem. Know what I did? Generated a string and eval'd it. Disgusting.

Comment: yes, I don't see another solution without reflection too. However, when using interfaces, the factory-pattern (or such), something like this is usually not required.

Answer (score -1):

Haha I just asked this question: [PHP passing a class as a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182993/php-passing-a-class-as-a-reference)

And you can't expand the `$args`. You could try passing `$args[0], $args[1]` etc.